# Confusion regarding dimensions in CNN

Tags: python, matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[image: img]
The above picture generated using Matlab's deep learning toolbox shows the architecture of a CNN created for a toy example. The input image is of size `25*20*7`, number of filters are 15 each of size `5*5` and padding is `same`. The output of the first convolution `conv1` is `25*20*15` which goes into maxpooling 1 operation of size `2*2` with stride `1` and padding `same`.

Based on my understanding, the role of maxpooling is to perform dimension reduction. However, in my code since the padding is set to `same` I understand that  the output of maxpooling will preserve the spatial dimension to its input which is `25*20*15`. That is why the output of maxpooling1 and the rest of the maxpooling is of the same dimension as its input and there is no change in the dimension in the remaining layers. AS an example, So, the output of maxpooling should have been: `(25 - 2 +2*1/1) + 1` = `23+2/1 + 1 = 25`. Similarly, for the second dimension maxpooling would yield: `(20 - 2 +2*1/1) + 1` = `18+2/1 + 1 = 20`. Thus, the output of maxpooling should be `25*20*15`.

This implies that maxpooling is not doing dimension reduction. Therefore, should I remove maxpooling if the padding option is set to `same`?

Please let me know how the dimensions are same after doing maxpooling and if same dimension then should I remove this operation? Or did I do some mistake?

Comment: Your question is not programming specific. Use https://datascience.stackexchange.com/  for help with deep learning questions.

Comment: ok, I have posted the question over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role of padding is different for convolutional and maxpooling layer. If padding=`same` in convolutional layer, it means that the output size (primarily height and width) remains the same as the input.
On the other hand, padding in pooling layers has a different functionality. The  purpose of pooling layers is to reduce the spatial dimensions (height and width). In pooling layers, padding = `same` does not mean that the spatial dimensions do not change. Padding in pooling is required to make up for overlaps when the input size and kernel size do not perfectly fit.

Answer (score -1):

**tldr:** If you want to reduce the image size in every step, use *padding=valid*. it's default option.

Maxpooilign is generally used for Downsampling and Reducing Overfitting.

If you use padding='same', it will stretch the image to input size, causing no drop in the size.

In the example below, input size is 4 * 4, pool is 2*2 and (default) stride is 2x2, so output is 2 * 2

[image: MaxPooling Example]

Find more examples on keras' [official site](https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/max_pooling2d/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. If the padding for maxpooling is kept `same` causes no change in dimension, then what is the point of having this option of `same`? Should I keep it or remove it?

Comment: Yes, you should, if your objective is to reduce dimension, you should use 'padding=valid'. There are other use cases of padding='same', but it is less popular than valid, that's why valid is the default option.